# Error: "Cannot implicitly convert type"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

I am working on one project and I have a question regarding the converting type. I want to create simple search for my project, but it keeps asking about `Ienumerable` type, which honestly I did not understand. Please help.

The problem:

> Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'PagedList.IPagedList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  C:\Users\Asus\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Nordstromapp\Nordstromapp\Controllers\ProductController.cs  38  24  Nordstromapp

My code:

```
{
    NordstromEntities _db;

    public ProductController()
    {
        _db = new NordstromEntities();
    }
    //
    // GET: /Product/

    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string CurrentSort, int? page, string searchString)
    {
        int pageSize = 10;
    int pageIndex = 1;
    pageIndex = page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page) : 1;

    ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;

    sortOrder = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "ID" : sortOrder;

    IPagedList<Product_list> products = null;



    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        products = products.Where(m => m.ID.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                               || m.Product_name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
    }

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "ID":
            if(sortOrder.Equals(CurrentSort))  
                products = _db.Product_list.OrderByDescending
                        (m => m.ID).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);   
            else
                products = _db.Product_list.OrderBy
                        (m => m.ID).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);   
            break;

        case "Product_name":
            if (sortOrder.Equals(CurrentSort))
                products = _db.Product_list.OrderByDescending
                        (m => m.Product_name).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
            else
                products = _db.Product_list.OrderBy
                        (m => m.Product_name).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
            break;

        case "Product_category":
            if (sortOrder.Equals(CurrentSort))
                products = _db.Product_list.OrderByDescending
                        (m => m.Product_category).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
            else
                products = _db.Product_list.OrderBy
                        (m => m.Product_category).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
            break;

        case "Price":
            if (sortOrder.Equals(CurrentSort))
                products = _db.Product_list.OrderByDescending
                        (m => m.Price).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
            else
                products = _db.Product_list.OrderBy
                        (m => m.Price).ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
            break;


    }
    return View(products);
}
```

Comment: On which line you get this error? Debug your code first.

Comment: It's after the first `if`: you are missing `.ToPagedList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `products` is indeed of type `IPagedList<Product_List>`, the call to `.Where()` on an instance of `IPagedList<Product_List>` *returns* an `IEnumerable<Product_List>`, which can't be implicitly converted.  Notice how you perform conversions here:

```
products = _db.Product_list.OrderByDescending(m => m.ID)
                           .ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
```

You just need to perform the same conversion after your `.Where()` call:

```
products = products.Where(m => m.ID.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) ||
                               m.Product_name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()))
                   .ToPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize);
```